# Sick of always typing in IP addresses for machines on my network

Tags: linux, windows, networking

In my home network I have a raspberry pi with some services,
I would like to access them inside and outside of the network without having to reconfigure the ip addresses in my apps on devices eg: phone, laptop etc.
I can edit the hosts file and add a name to point to an IP in home network
but on my phone or tablet can not do that.

What better way to use my services inside and outside my network without having to reconfigure addresses?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System: "Most prominently, it translates easily memorized domain names to the numerical IP addresses needed for the purpose of locating computer services and devices worldwide."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Propagating Names for non-machine IP addresses in a home network](http://superuser.com/questions/272672/propagating-names-for-non-machine-ip-addresses-in-a-home-network), [Use name instead of IP address for home network](http://superuser.com/questions/233575/use-name-instead-of-ip-address-for-home-network?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access services on your home network, without having to keep track of your home network's public IP address manually, you'll need to have a [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dns) client running from inside your home network. Then, configure your home gateway (usually a router, modem, or router/modem combo) to [forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) incoming traffic on the appropriate ports to the internal systems that are providing the services. After that's done, just configure your client devices (e.g.: phone, laptop, etc.) to use the domain name assigned by your DNS provider and (if necessary) the port you've configured to be forwarded to the service they're accessing.

Comment: I already have a no-ip client run in raspberry pi for access it from outside of the network. The problem is make it works inside of my network. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Problem solved. In my home network I activate the DSL-3680 Router nat loopback option via telnet.